# Oracle SQL view data from temporary table

Tags: oracle, temporary

I have a temporary table in Oracle 10g with "ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;"
How can I view data from this table?

Comment: You can only see data in that table from within the same session that inserted the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify **ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS** ,

the data will stay until the end of your session. If the table was created with "on commit preserve rows" then data will remain until the end of the current session. If it was created with "on commit delete rows" then it will remain until the next commit or rollback.